# How to set variables to equal what the user inputs into a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jdialog

So I'm trying to get input from the user from a JDialog, here is the code within the JDialog:

```
public void addPipeUI(){
     Integer[] grade = {1,2,3,4,5};
     Integer[] colour = {0, 1, 2};
     float length;
     int diameter;
     boolean chemResist, innerIns, outerRein;
     GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);

     JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
     dialog.setSize(400, 400);
     dialog.setLocation(250, 250);
     dialog.setTitle("Add Pipe");
     dialog.setLayout(gridLayout);
     dialog.setVisible(true);

     dialog.add(new JLabel("Grade"));
     JComboBox gradeField = new JComboBox(grade);
     dialog.add(gradeField);

     dialog.add(new JLabel("Colour"));
     JComboBox colourField = new JComboBox(colour);
     dialog.add(colourField);

     dialog.add(new JLabel("Length (Meters)"));
     JTextField lengthField = new JTextField();
     dialog.add(lengthField);

     dialog.add(new JLabel("Diameter (Inches)"));
     JTextField diameterField = new JTextField();
     dialog.add(diameterField);

     JRadioButton innerInsField = new JRadioButton("Inner Insluation");
     dialog.add(innerInsField);

     JRadioButton outerReinField = new JRadioButton("Outer Reinforcement");
     dialog.add(outerReinField);

     JRadioButton chemResistField = new JRadioButton("Chemical Resistance");
     dialog.add(chemResistField);

     JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
     dialog.add(ok);


 }
```

At the top you can see what information I want the user to input.

**When the OK button is pressed I want to make the local variables equal what the user has input and then return those variables to my Main class to be processed.** 
I feel like I need a actionlistener on the OK button but when I do that the local variables cant be used and now I'm just confused. How can I make the local variables equal what the user enters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an action listener to your button so that you can catch the click event

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String length = lengthField.getText();
        System.out.println("length=" + length);
    }
});
```

In order to access the local variable `lengthField` you need to make if final:

```
final JTextField lengthField = new JTextField();
```

This is because the action listener is an anonymous inner class. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) states

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

Another alternative would be to make it an instance variable of your class.

Comment: So if I make all the inputs final, I could then use them within the actionlistener? because that would solve my problem I think!

Comment: @benharris Yes you could access them if declared as final.